# Connect devise User model to other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to connect the model User to the other models in my Rails app.
I use the [the gem 'devise'](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

I have created a User model.
I already got a Post model and a Comment model.
They are connect like so:

**Post model:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

**Comment model:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :posts
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Routes:**

```
devise_for :users
resources :posts do  
    resources :comments
end
```

**Notes:**

There is no User controller.

**What I want:**

I want that a User logs in and he should only be able to see his posts.
In a real world App that wouldn't make sense I know.

**When I do this:**

```
rails c
User.first.posts.create(title: "foo", content: "bar")
this works
```

How can I manage to make that form working?
**View:**

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.posts.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller:**

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @post = @user.posts.create(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**View:**

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    # whatever you need
  end
end
```

Comment: It's already one step closer. Now i got this error messsage: Couldn't find User without an ID, error is in this line:         @user = User.find(params[:id])

Comment: You don't need this line. You can use `current_user` instead.

Comment: I have removed that line, now i got an error message at:  def new
@post = current_user.posts.build
end, undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Should I post column names of all models?

Comment: Now it tells me this: 

undefined method `user_posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000002663d50>:0x007ffd3c2709e8>

error in this line: 
<%= form_for([ current_user, @post]) do |f| %>

Comment: <%= form_for @post do |f| %>

Comment: Thanks you sir it works now. one last question. how would you adjust the show to fetch all posts by this current logged in user?

Comment: If you need to display all current user's posts, you need the `index` action in the controller, where you can do that: `@posts = current_user.posts`. Simple enough.